# Подсказка при вводе в QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete

Есть кастомный QTextEdit, как в него добавить всплывающие подсказки при вводе, как в Qt Creator, Sublime или любой IDE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого подойдёт класс [QCompleter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html)

Официальный пример создания кастомного completer для кастомного QTextEdit от Qt:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html